# Error with sklearn auc function caused by Pandas operations

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, auc

I'm trying to read some info from a .txt file and then use the sklearn auc function on this data. The .txt file is a mixture of strings, ints and floats and it also has some lines at the top that I have no use for as well as some blank rows. So some pre-processing is required to convert it into a usable data frame. If I clean the text file manually, the following code runs successfully.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import auc

# Read the data and drop the NaN column produced at the end
fp = r"(<full file path to cleaned file>.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(fp, delimiter = '\t')
df.dropna(axis = 1, inplace=True)

# Convert the first and second columns to numpy ndarrays
kk_array = df.iloc[:,2].to_numpy()
MM_array = df.iloc[:,1].to_numpy()

# Calculate the area under the curve 
print(auc(kk_array,MM_array))
```

When I try to do this cleaning with Pandas, I get the following error:

```
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1269, in diff
    a = op(a[slice1], a[slice2])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import auc

# Read the data ignoring the blank rows and data about the file near the top.
fp = r"<full file path to raw file>.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(fp, delimiter = '\t', skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,15])
df.dropna(axis = 1, inplace=True)

# Combine the string columns in the first 4 rows into one and make that the header.
list_a = list(df) # this returns a list of the headers
list_b = list(df.iloc[0])
list_c = list(df.iloc[1])
list_d = list(df.iloc[2])
new_header_list = [a + "/" + b + "/" + c + "/" + d for a,b,c,d in zip(list_a, list_b, list_c, list_d)]

# Now drop the redundant rows and change the header.
df = df[3:]
df.columns = new_header_list

# Convert the first and second columns to numpy ndarrays
kk_array = df.iloc[:,2].to_numpy()
MM_array = df.iloc[:,1].to_numpy()

# Calculate the area under the curve 
print(auc(kk_array,MM_array))
```

Now, clearly my issue is that kk_array and MM_array are being interpreted as strings. In my first code snippet that works, kk_array and MM_array are type "Array of float64", but it the code that doesn't work, they are type "Array of object".

I have tried a few methods to force them to be floats e.g df.apply(pd.to_numeric) but nothing seems to be working. Can someone please help me understand what's going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You can specify the datatype in pd.to_numpy(). Try passing dtype=np.float32 or some other numeric variant and see if the problem persists. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html

Comment: Also worth noting on that page above: "For a mix of numeric and non-numeric types, the output array will have object dtype." It is likely that your df column contains non-numeric data (or is represented as a string).

Comment: dtype np.float32 did the trick, thanks a mil. I think you're right that the column data is (was) being represented by a string but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly copied from a comment above for anyone else's future reference:

You can specify the datatype in pd.to_numpy(). Try passing dtype=np.float32 or some other numeric variant and see if the problem persists. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html